# Tomcat has stopped generating stdout logs

Tags: tomcat, logging, tomcat7, stdout

We have tomcat server in our production environment. **Suddenly tomcat has stopped generating stdout logs.**
Last generated log by tomcat is one month ago and the size of stdout log file
is **5006 KB.**
What is the reason behind there is no stdout log generated suddenly?
As logs are crucial factor for us please help me in digging out this problem